# Testimonial widget from Elementor layout changes after first loop

Tags: wordpress, widget, elementor

Having a problem with the testimonial slider. There are 3 templates used as 3 slides in the testimonial slider – inserted using short codes into the slider. No matter which shortcode or template used, always the slide at the start of the second loop/iteration of the slides going by has its layout disrupted.

How can I solve this please?

The page I need help with: https://www.bighitsdigitalmedia.org/  Midway down the page underneath the search bar please.

Not matter what css or template I link to, the property at the start of second loop has its layout broken and differently from the other slides and even how the same template as a slide appears on its first loop.  I'd like the layout of the properties to stay in the same consistent layout please.